# How can I make a secret easter egg when a certain number is typed into a number field?

Tags: android

I made a little currency converter and I wanted to add a simple little easter egg to have some fun. The easter egg is: If the number "42" or "69" is typed into the text field, and the "convert" button is pressed, it will show a special Toast instead of the converted currency.

Comment: Nothing so far.

Comment: You should really consider providing what you've tried so far, particularly code, if you want an answer. Consider this resource: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your question is essentially this: "How do I write an if statement"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic would be

```
if(number == 42 || number == 49) {
//show special toast
} 
else{
    // show regular currency
    }
```